# Window object is provided by the browser or by javascript engine?

Tags: javascript, window-object

I there I'm following a course where the instructor says that the object window is provided by the javascript engine, my question is, the object window is really provided by javascript engine or by the browser? Because in the window object are the API's provided by the browser like fetch, setTimeout, etc, to interact with our javascript code. I can't understand if the javascript engine generates the window object and than inherits the API's from the browser, or something else is happening.

Comment: A bit of both? The specs say that there should be a global object which provides stuff like `setTimeout`. In browsers this global object is `window`. So, in effect, the engine is doing it to comply with the specs. However, you're right that some of the DOM related functionality isn't really part of the JS engine. It's the browser API which is also exposed through the global object.

Comment: Window is created by browser, in Node.js, for example, there is no window object, there is global instead realized by Node

Comment: http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/

Comment: @KooiInc - jquery is rarely the answer

Comment: @Bravo other than having "jquery" in the link and a jQuery logo being present on the page, there is *nothing* jQuery related in the article.

Comment: @Bravo it is an explanation of `window` vs `document` and as such has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: @KooiInc and as such has nothing to do with this question, since `document` is just a shorthand for `window.document` because `document` is a property of `window`, and since `window` is the so-called global object in a browser, there is no misunderstanding between `window` and `document` that needs to be explained

Answer (score 0):

window object is created by the browser, not JavaScript engine.JavaScript engine interacts with the window object.